# How to use software webgl engine in Chrome 18

Tags: google-chrome, webgl, chromium

I'd like to test out the new SwiftShader-based software WebGL engine which is [allegedly in Chrome 18](http://blog.chromium.org/2012/03/moar-better-graphics.html). I'm running 18.0.1025.165 on Mac OS X 10.7.3. I tried this command line [(suggested here)](http://blog.chromium.org/2012/02/gpu-accelerating-2d-canvas-and-enabling.html), but when I visit something with WebGL, it just says that it is disabled:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome  --blacklist-accelerated-compositing --blacklist-webgl
```

Is SwiftShader in the Mac version of Chrome 18? Is there a different trick I should use to enable it?

Comment: I entered a bug report: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=127813

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently SwiftShader is only available for Chrome under Windows. Is there any particular reason why you need it on Mac OS? Apple typically has adequate graphics hardware and OpenGL drivers.

Comment: Primarily for testing. I'd like to be able to test how my stuff works in software rendering, without having to boot up a Windows machine or VM.

Comment: Also, where did you get that information? Every blog post I saw about Chrome 18 said SwiftShader was available on Windows and Mac (but not Linux).

Comment: Francis is right. Swiftshader is not available on Mac. See http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=127813